# Python AES encryption of long integer

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes

I currently have Java code that encrypts a long using AES:

```
final static byte[] KEY = {13, 92, 9, 7, 111, 84, 19, 3, 20, 76, 67, 47, 12, 2, 32, 99};

final static Base64 ENCODER = new Base64(-1, new byte[0], true);
final static Key S_KEY = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");

static String encrypt(long aid) {
    byte[] clear = Longs.toByteArray(aid);

    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, S_KEY);

        byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(clear);

        System.out.println("Byte array: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));

        return ENCODER.encodeAsString(bytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I want to implement this same routine in Python; this is what I have:

```
key= bytearray([13, 92, 9, 7, 111, 84, 19, 3, 20, 76, 67, 47, 12, 2, 32, 99])

def encrypt(account_id):
    bts = b_a(account_id)

    encryption_suite = AES.new(str(key), AES.MODE_ECB)
    encrypted_id = encryption_suite.encrypt(str(bts))

    return (encrypted_id)


def b_a(val):
    result = bytearray(16)

    for i in range(15,0, -1):
        result[i] = val & 255L
        val >>= 8

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = bytearray(encrypt(2122))
    for a in e: print a
```

The Java output is:

```
Byte array: [34, -106, 18, 47, -94, 7, -4, 88, 3, -81, 13, 30, 30, 57, -59, -66]
```

However, on python I get: (reduced)

```
[195,69,95,244,125,237,1,80,125,5,219,113,119,27,92,33]
```

Why is this? I want to move my Java code to Python.

Comment: What byte order is this: `Longs.toByteArray(aid)`? Your Python code seems to be big endian.

Comment: If you're using ECB, where's your IV? Also, you're not using ECB in Java.

Comment: Debugging shows that both byte arrays in Java and Python are equivalent and big-endian.

Comment: Oracle JDK AES defaults to ECB.

Comment: Then it's probably a missing IV. Java uses a random one by default that you can get with `cipher.getIV()`. If you set the same IV for both, the results should be the same.